# Scrollbar Question

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, scrollviewer

How to check whether the caretposition is inside the visible region of a window.

I am using Richtextbox inside a Scrollviewer.Whenever the cursor moves to the non-visible area of Richtextbox I need to call the scrollviewer's line down.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but could you just set the RichTextBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility, instead of putting your RichTextBox in a ScrollViewer?